# Indent wrapped text in table

Tags: html, indentation, css-tables

I am creating a table in a html document. If the text is too long in a cell, I want it to wrap on to a new line (no problem). What I am struggling to achieve is making the text on the new line(s) to be indented.

E.g. instead of

```
A very long bit |
of text in this |
table           |
```

I want:

```
A very long bit |
   of text in   |
   this table   |
```

Is it possible to achieve this in CSS or other means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
td {
   text-indent: -4.0em;
   padding-left: 4.0em;
}
```

This indents the entire cell text and then pulls the first line back to the original left side.

Comment: And another since I already made it may as well post it ... http://jsfiddle.net/xeUsp/1/

Answer (score 0):

How smart do you need it to be? You could do something simple (and dirty in my example):

```
s = "a long string";
regExp = /(.{5})(.*)/;
cut = s.replace(regExp, "$1<p>$2</p>");
```

Then indent or add padding to the text inside the paragraph. Of course this will only work for the first occurrence.